# Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, groovy

I am newbee to Groovy, Gradle, IntelliJ IDEA, Gradle Plugin Development.
Whenever I click on the publishToMavenLocal, I am getting the following error,

> > Task :compileGroovy FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':compileGroovy' property 'classpath' during up-to-date check. >
>     Failed to create MD5 hash for file content. Deprecated Gradle features
>     were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0. BUILD
>     FAILED in 11s 2 actionable tasks: 2 executed Data error (cyclic
>     redundancy check)

Can anyone help me resolve this ? This is a pure Gradle plugin developed using Groovy.

Comment: I have tried Invalidate Cache/Restart, it didnt work. I tried deleting the .idea folder and reimport all the projects, but it didnt work.

Comment: The message says that you're using gradle 5.0 with some deprecated features. Above the error in the output you should be able to see warnings - what do they say?

Comment: I thin ksomething is wrong with your declared inputs. Can you show the task configuration, please?

Comment: @Opal There is only one warning that says - publications cannot be applied to groovy.lang.closure